# type-deduction using auto for functors

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I am relatively new to the C++11 features. I have question regarding the auto feature and how it type-deduces functors. Consider the following code snippet:

```
bool test1(double a, double b) {
   return (a<b);
}

   bool test2(double a, double b) {
       return (a>b);
   }

   struct Test1 {
       bool operator()(double a, double b) {
          return (a<b);
       }
   };

   struct Test2 {
       bool operator()(double a, double b){
          return (a>b);
       }
   };

   int main() {
       const bool ascending = false; 
      auto comparator =  ascending? test1:test2; // works fine
      auto comparator2 = ascending? Test1():Test2(); // compiler error: imcompatible types
      std::function<bool(double, double)> comparator3 = ascending? Test1():Test2(); // compiler error: imcompatible types;

   }
```

While auto (and std::function) works fine for the functions, it fails (type-deduction) for the function objects. Why is this? I am missing something fundamental w.r.t type-deduction here.

(I am using Visual Studio 2012)

Comment: `Test1()` is a `Test1` and `Test2()` is a `Test2`. You're creating instances of the classes.

Comment: Doesn't `comparator` has type `(bool) (*)(double, double)`?

Comment: not really an answer to your question, but for a direction to solve the problem, you can use polymorphism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per Paragraph 5.16/3 of the C++11 Standard on the *conditional* (`?`) operator:

> [...] if the second and third operand have different types and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class
>   type, or if both are glvalues of the same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an
>   attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the other. [...]
>   **If both can be
>   converted, or one can be converted but the conversion is ambiguous, the program is ill-formed**. [...]

In your case, neither `Test1` nor `Test2` can be converted to the other type. This is why the compiler is complaining about "incompatible types".

Nptice, that if this wasn't the case, the type of `comparator2` and `comparator3` would be determined at *run-time* based on the value of `ascending`. However, C++ is a *statically-typed* language, meaning that **the type of all objects has to be determined at compile-time**.

If you need to perform a run-time selection of a comparator and hold the result in one variable, consider first assigning both objects to a functor of the same type that can encapsulate them both, and *then* performing the selection:

```
    std::function<bool(double, double)> c1 = Test1();
    std::function<bool(double, double)> c2 = Test2();
    auto c = (ascending) ? c1 : c2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of the problem and the solution

Comment: @Skyrus: If you believe this answers your question, please consider marking the answer as accepted (or any other answer you may prefer).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the two options for the conditional operator `?:` must be convertible to a single common type.  In this case, `Test1` and `Test2` are not related, and it's not possible to use the operator like that.

However, this is legal:

```
 int main() {
      const bool ascending = false; 
      std::function<bool(double, double)> t1 = Test1();
      std::function<bool(double, double)> t2 = Test2();
      auto comparator4 = ascending? t1: t2;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

`test1` and `test2` both are of type `bool(double, double)`, so the type of the conditional expression is the same no matter what branch you take. The type of `Test1()` is `Test1`, that of `Test2()` is `Test2`. So the expression has no common type. Both of these types *can* be used to construct a `std::function<bool(double, double)>` object, using the constructor template of that class, but this kind of cast isn't performed for expressions automatically: you have to cast manually:

```
auto comparator3 = ascending ? std::function<bool(double, double)>(Test1())
                             : std::function<bool(double, double)>(Test2());
```